# Animated menu Implementation

Tags: java, android, android-gradle-plugin, dependencies, build.gradle

I am trying to implement Animator Menu as, https://github.com/xuechinahb/AnimatorMenu

But I can't find any dependency code that can be imported. Could you please help me with identifying the dependencies used.

Comment: You can use their java class directly with  NineOldAndroids library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can download and add this project as a module and use their class and properties.

Comment: which one @ankur

Comment: Try this one: https://github.com/xuechinahb/AnimatorMenu/tree/master/AnimatorMenu

Comment: your given link.